# Creating new classes from code

Tags: java, eclipse, class, reflection, eclipse-jdt

Is there a way to create a new java class during execution? All the information about the class (name, modifiers, methods, fields, etc.) exists. Now I want to create that class. An idea was to create a new file and write the stuff to that file, c'est fini! But I think there are more elegant ways to do that, maybe with JDT?

Comment: Do you really need this? Sounds a bit hacky...

Comment: @Tobiask, a lot of middleware does it. It's fairly common task (simple case JSP is exactly that), need some lib like ASM/BCEL  and a custom classloader and it's done.

Answer (score 4):

Either use `BCEL` to create byte code and class files (the hard way) or create the source code in memory and use the Java 6 Compiler API (that's what I would do). But with Compiler API you need a Java SDK while running the application, a JRE is not sufficient.

**Further Reading**

- [The Java 6.0 Compiler API](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html)

(There a lot of tutorials on the web)

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing an eclipse plugin and you want your tooling to generate code into a project, you can interact with JDT using the [AST](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm).  There is also a method to call the Eclipse batch compiler from your runtime.

```
AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS3);
CompilationUnit unit = ast.newCompilationUnit();
PackageDeclaration packageDeclaration = ast.newPackageDeclaration();
packageDeclaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("example"));
unit.setPackage(packageDeclaration);
ImportDeclaration importDeclaration = ast.newImportDeclaration();
QualifiedName name = 
    ast.newQualifiedName(
    ast.newSimpleName("java"),
    ast.newSimpleName("util"));
importDeclaration.setName(name);
importDeclaration.setOnDemand(true);
unit.imports().add(importDeclaration);
TypeDeclaration type = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
type.setInterface(false);
type.modifiers().add(ast.newModifier(Modifier.ModifierKeyword.PUBLIC_KEYWORD));
    type.setName(ast.newSimpleName("HelloWorld"));
// ....
```

Long winded :-) but you have access to the JDT java core model as you go.

If you need to generate files into your eclipse workspace, there are also template based options, like [JET](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JET/jet_tutorial1.html).

But if you want to dynamically generate and load a .class file in the runtime of a java application try @Andreas_D suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at code generation libraries,
http://cglib.sourceforge.net/
http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/